# How to specify path to file in Java?

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, path

how to add path to File Scanner in Java? I use Ubuntu and Intellij. I think I do everythink ok, but it still doesn't work :(

Code:

```
 File file = new File("/abc/file.txt");
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /abc/file.txt (No such file or directory)
```

[image: inte]

Comment: Please post all your code and error messages as correctly-formatted text. You can edit your question to add this.

Comment: Does `/abc/file.txt` exist on your filesystem?

Comment: / is the root of your server, not the root of your project.

Comment: So, what is root of my project then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `abc` folder is under `src` and you're using absolute pathing with the leading `/` which states it at the root of your file system.

Move the folder to the root folder of the project and then reference is as

```
File file = new File("abc/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in linux you have this file in correct path:
eg. /path/to/file/filename.txt

You can try this:

For windows:

```
File file = new File("\\path\\to\\file\\filename.txt");
```

For Linux:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file/filename.txt");
```